# RequiresUniqueEmail in SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After reading many blogs and posts on this website, I think trying to override RequiresUniqueEmail in SimpleMembershipProvider seems like a lot a code for just a trival thing.

So I'm looking for some advice about what I have done. I have added a unique index on the email column in the database, then I have a try catch block that catches any sql exceptions.

I the look inside the exception message for the email address that the user posted, if I find it then I return a message saying "email already in use", else another message.

This works on my machine, and the error message I receive is:

```
Message=Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserProfile'
with unique index 'idx_UniqueEmail'. The duplicate key value is
(myemail@test.com).
```

As I'm not an experienced programmer, It would be appreciated for any feedback.

My code is below.

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
      var errorMessage = e.Message.ToLower();
      ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMessage.Contains(model.Email) ? "Sorry the email address is already in use." : "Sorry an error has occured");
}
```

Comment: You could implement IValidatableObject in your entity and pass back a custom error when there's an email matching the entered one already in the database. (Assuming EF is being used)

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for reply, I'm not using EF for this, but will look into IValidatableObject

Comment: You can use Remote Validation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Hi ataravati, thanks forgot all about that, I remember now reading about it a couple of month ago. Thanks for jogging my memory

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembershipProvider is not email aware. It literally has no concept of email as you'll note if you look at the default auto-generated schema. This is why many of the legacy MembershipProvider APIs are unsupported by the SimpleMembershipProvider implementation.

You can of course add an email column to the UserProfile table (as I assume you've done), but the provider has no mechanism for implementing RequiresUniqueEmail, and is in fact hardwired to always return false. Adding a database constraint will work to some extent but only by causing an Exception when the the profile is updated. It's not at all elegant, but should work.

You could tell SimpleMembershipProvider to use email as username when initializing the provider, but this means losing userName field and requiring users to login with email/password which may not be preferable.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(connectionString, "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);
```

An alternative is to extend the SimpleMembershipProvider, make it email aware, and implement RequiresUniqueEmail.

Take a look at [BetterMembership.Net](https://github.com/TheCodeKing/BetterMembership.Net) on GutHub, it does exactly that and can be used as a replacement for SimpleMembershipProvider. The email column is specified on the provider, and it supports RequiresUniqueEmail out-of-the-box.

```
<add name="BetterProvider" 
   type="BetterMembership.Web.BetterMembershipProvider, BetterMembership, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=737bc70442f2c4af" 
   connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
   userIdColumn="UserId"
   userNameColumn="UserName"
   userTableName="UserProfile"
   userEmailColumn="Email"    
   requiresUniqueEmail="true"   
   autoInitialize="true" />
```